# Correction for measurement error

Tags: regression, measurement-error, bias-correction

Let's suppose that the true model is:
$$ y_t^* = x_t^* \beta + e_t^* $$
and suppose that data on $x_t^*$ is observed with error:
$$ x_t = x_t^* + u_t $$
If we consider the regression $y_t^* = x_t \beta + e_t$, we have the issue that the regressor is endogenous, i.e. $E(e_t x_t) \neq 0$. 
So that the OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$ will be biased and inconsistent.

I found that: 
$$ E[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}] = \beta \frac{Var(x_t^*)}{Var(x_t^*) + \sigma_u^2} $$ so the expected value of the estimator is downward biased.

What are common ways to correct for correct for the measurement error?

Comment: Small correction: The estimator is not downward biased, but biased towards zero.

Comment: If the error is similar to random noise, then this particular problem can be mitigated by taking repeated measurements at each value of x.

Comment: @E.Sommer Can you give us the difference between the two?

Comment: If $\beta > 0$, $E[\hat{\beta}]< \beta$. If $\beta < 0$, $E[\hat{\beta}]> \beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from obtaining a more reliable measurement of $x$, there is not much one can do from an econometric perspective. But if you find something *despite* measurement error, and the quantity of $\beta$ is not crucial, you are generally fine.